# Using 'resource' method inside Route::controller(<class>)->group(...)

Tags: php, laravel

I'm editing my app routing files, to get them as tidiest as possible.
So I've done this in my "web.php":

```
Route::controller(AlquilerController::class)->group(function ($hola) {
   
    //Debug lines
    error_log("This");
    error_log(get_class($this)); //Illuminate\Routing\RouteFileRegistrar.
    error_log("hola");
    error_log(get_class($hola)); //Illuminate\Routing\Router.

    Route::get('alquileres/busqueda', 'busqueda')->name('alquileres.busqueda');
    Route::get('alquileres/busqueda_texto', 'busquedaTexto')->name('alquileres.busqueda_texto');

    Route::middleware('auth')->get('alquileres/mis_alquileres', 'mis_alquileres')->name('alquileres.mis_alquileres');

    Route::post('/alquileres/filter_texto',  'filterTexto')->name('alquileres.filter_texto');
    Route::get('/alquileres/filter_texto',  'filterTexto')->name('alquileres.filter_texto_url');

    Route::post('/alquileres/filter',  'filter')->name('alquileres.filter');
    Route::get('/alquileres/filter',  'filter')->name('alquileres.filter_url');

    Route::resource('alquileres',AlquilerController::class)->parameters(['alquileres' => 'alquiler']);
});
```

Despite this works fine, I found redundant the line:
`Route::resource('alquileres',AlquilerController::class)->parameters(['alquileres' => 'alquiler']);`, since I'm repeating the text "AlquilerController::class", both  in the argument of 'Route::controller', and then in the second argument of ' Route::resource'.

Is there any way to avoid this? I've tried to do some 'error_log' at the begining of the 'group' callback body, just to see what I was getting, but I couldn't find a solution to this.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

how about declaring a variable before route group with the value of controller class and then use that variable in the route group class avoiding repeating

```
$controllerClass = AlquilerController::class;

Route::controller($controllerClass)->group(function () use ($controllerClass) {

    Route::get('alquileres/busqueda', 'busqueda')->name('alquileres.busqueda');
    Route::get('alquileres/busqueda_texto', 'busquedaTexto')->name('alquileres.busqueda_texto');

    Route::middleware('auth')->get('alquileres/mis_alquileres', 'mis_alquileres')->name('alquileres.mis_alquileres');

    Route::post('/alquileres/filter_texto',  'filterTexto')->name('alquileres.filter_texto');
    Route::get('/alquileres/filter_texto',  'filterTexto')->name('alquileres.filter_texto_url');

    Route::post('/alquileres/filter',  'filter')->name('alquileres.filter');
    Route::get('/alquileres/filter',  'filter')->name('alquileres.filter_url');

    Route::resource('alquileres', $controllerClass)->parameters(['alquileres' => 'alquiler']);
});
```